# How can I access these json elements with jQuery and getJSON?

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

I have an array returned from an elasticsearch query as follows:

```
[
   [
      "took",
      2
   ],
   [
      "timed_out",
      false
   ],
   [
      "_shards",
      {
         "total":5,
         "successful":5,
         "failed":0
      }
   ],
   [
      "hits",
      {
         "total":1,
         "max_score":0.2712221,
         "hits":[
            {
               "_index":"myindex",
               "_type":"mytype",
               "_id":"1",
               "_score":0.2712221,
               "_source":{
                  "id":1465,
                  "level":"Mid-Level",
                  "first":"Kung-Wei",
                  "last":"Liu",
                  "designation":"Associate",
                  "company":"Sullivan & Cromwell",
                  "email":"89liu1017@gmail.com",
                  "phone":"phone",
                  "city":"Hong Kong",
                  "country":"China",
                  "industry":"Legal",
                  "status":"none",
                  "owner":"hector@fastmail.se",
                  "remarks":"looks unusal",
                  "experience":"unknown ",
                  "created_at":"2014-05-09 06:01:50.401076"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
]
```

Using a getJSON call, how can I access "designation" or "city" for example? My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("/search", function(data) {
    //var txt1 = 'You have ' +data["total_count"]+ ' campaigns';
    //$("#notification").html(txt1);
    var txt  = '<table><tr>';
     $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        txt += '<tr><td><a href="#" class="a"  id="' +this["id"]+ '">' +this["name"]+ '</a></td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["id"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["first"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["last"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["designation"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["company"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +this["experience"]+ '</td>';
        });//end each
        txt += '</tr></table>';
 $("#results").append(txt);
    });//end json
});
```

`this["variable"]` does not work!

All help gratefully received, thank you guys.

Comment: `results` is an array of arrays, not an array of objects. You have to drill down several levels before you get to an object with `id`, `first`, etc. fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
 var txt  = '<table><tr>';
 $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    if(key == 3)
    {
     txt += '<td>' + value[1].hits[0]._source.designation + '</td>';   
     txt += '<td>' + value[1].hits[0]._source.city + '</td>'; 
    }
});
 txt += '</tr></table>';
 $("#results").append(txt);
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/7r275/

Comment: this works but how can I do it without console.log in the way that I am trying to do it in the jquery above? Many thanks!

Comment: Brilliant Robert, thank you. Different approach, slightly from above, but again just what I need. I am very grateful for this economic and graceful snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7cwS/)

```
    var xxx = [
   [
      "took",
      2
   ],
   [
      "timed_out",
      false
   ],
   [
      "_shards",
      {
         "total":5,
         "successful":5,
         "failed":0
      }
   ],
   [
      "hits",
      {
         "total":1,
         "max_score":0.2712221,
         "hits":[
            {
               "_index":"myindex",
               "_type":"mytype",
               "_id":"1",
               "_score":0.2712221,
               "_source":{
                  "id":1465,
                  "level":"Mid-Level",
                  "first":"Kung-Wei",
                  "last":"Liu",
                  "designation":"Associate",
                  "company":"Sullivan & Cromwell",
                  "email":"89liu1017@gmail.com",
                  "phone":"phone",
                  "city":"Hong Kong",
                  "country":"China",
                  "industry":"Legal",
                  "status":"none",
                  "owner":"hector@fastmail.se",
                  "remarks":"looks unusal",
                  "experience":"unknown ",
                  "created_at":"2014-05-09 06:01:50.401076"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
];

    console.log(xxx[3][1].hits[0]._source.designation);
    console.log(xxx[3][1].hits[0]._source.city);
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("/search", function(data) {
var item = data[3][1].hits[0]._source;
    var txt  = '<table><tr>';
        txt += '<tr><td><a href="#" class="a"  id="' +item["id"]+ '">' +item["name"]+ '</a></td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["id"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["first"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["last"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["designation"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["company"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' +item["experience"]+ '</td>';
        txt += '</tr></table>';
 $("#results").append(txt);
    });//end json
});
```

Comment: not sure! I just want to know how to access "designation" and "city"

Comment: yes, works fine in the console but how can I reproduce it in HTML? Thank you.

Comment: remove each loop then instead of `xxx` use `data`

Comment: sorry, you got me there. Not sure what you mean. I would like to be able to do txt = this[something,something."city"] How do I navigate the various levels to arrive at that? I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: scholar and a gent, thank you. Just what I am looking for because I can now generalize from this to access other elements of thiscarray, and others. Much obliged.